# VBA Spinbutton increment value textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to  change the data values of textboxes  by using a spinbutton
The data are written in an Excel table ..... could you explain to me which
syntax I should use or perhaps could you show me an example?

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
'Range("G15").Value = SpinButton1.Value
 
Dim I As Integer
 
 
For I = 2 To 10 Step 1
TextBox2.Value = Ws.Range("A"& I)
   Next
```

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/spin-button.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code i gives a good result but but why do i need an   msgbox ? Without msgbox it doesn't function ... strange ...

```
 Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

Dim I As Integer

For I = 2 To 10 Step 1
MsgBox ("La valeur de la Textbox" & I & " est de " & TextBox2)
ComboBox1.Value = Ws.Range("A" & I)
ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1.Value
TextBox2.Value = Ws.Range("B" & I)
TextBox3.Value = Ws.Range("C" & I)
TextBox4.Value = Ws.Range("D" & I)
TextBox5.Value = Ws.Range("E" & I)
TextBox6.Value = Ws.Range("F" & I)
TextBox7.Value = Ws.Range("G" & I)
TextBox8.Value = Ws.Range("H" & I)
TextBox9.Value = Ws.Range("I" & I)

'Range("G15").Value = SpinButton1.Value
Next
```